# Generate POJOs without an .xsd?

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am looking at JAXB as a way to unmarshal some XML which gets returned from a web service's API into POJOs, but I want to generate the POJOs first instead of writing/annotating them by hand. I came across xjc (POJO generator from JAXB), however it requires an XSD I believe and the web service returns just the XML and there is no XSD/DTD available, so I was wondering what the best way is of going about this.

- Is there a way to generate POJOs from straight XML? I am happy to assume all fields are String fields, I don't need type safety.
- Alternatively, there are ways to 'reverse engineer' an XSD from an XML file - are these any good? If so, any particular reason why this functionality isn't built in to tools like xjc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out the JAXBuilder Eclipse plug-in, which allows you to create a project in Eclipse and drop in either xsd or xml files and they will be automagically parsed into POJOs. It gives you the option of using either Castor or JAXB2 as the generator, and has some config options.

However, I found the direct XML -> POJO conversion to be a little temperamental, so I opted instead to use the free web-based http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html to generate an xsd from my xml, and then copy and paste this into the Eclipse JAXBuilder project to get POJOs. This approach is clearly not programatically perfect or scalable (copying and pasting bits of XML around) but seems to be a pretty good start to play with JAXB a little bit.